# Getting back value from data / ambiguous use of

Tags: ios, swift, variables, ios8

```
class Data {
    class Entry {
        let filename : String
        let heading : String
        let referenceville: String
        init(fname : String, heading : String, referenceville : String) {
            self.heading = heading
            self.filename = fname
            self.referenceville = referenceville
        }
    }

    let places = [
        Entry(fname: "bordeaux.jpg", heading: "Heading 1", referenceville : "bordeaux"),
        Entry(fname: "lyon.jpg", heading: "Heading 2", referenceville : "lyo
n"),            Entry(fname: "tours.jpg", heading: "Heading 3", referenceville : "tours"),
        ]

 subscript(index: String) -> NSArray {
            switch index {
            case "places" : return places
            case ...
            default: return []
            }
```

In class Data, there will have a lot of places (places1, places2, places3,...).
I would like to get back the value heading. I ve done the following code but it doesn't work. It return ambiguous use of heading.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CircuitsTableViewCell

     let key = "places"
     let data = Data()
     var entry: AnyObject = data[key][indexPath.row]
     println(entry.heading)
     return cell2
    }
```

But if i put directly the variable as a fixed value it's working. But i need to use a variable. It miss me something but i don't know what.

```
var entry = data.places[indexPath.row]
   println(entry.heading)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know that the type of the items in the `places` array is always `Entry`, cast the item explicitly

```
var entry = data[key][indexPath.row] as! Entry
```

Comment: it returns use of undeclared type "entry" . ??

Comment: put the `class Entry` block out of the `class Data` block or is there a particular reason to define a class in another?

Comment: What's the reason? Using your code it works the same way outside the block

Comment: If you have to keep `Entry` within `Data` you have to cast to `Data.Entry`